# Scroll Anchor Offset on First Click Mobile

Tags: html, css

I have an anchor on my page that is set to scroll to the form session, but for some reason on mobile the scroll only goes to the correct place after the first click, on the first click the scroll ends in the top session.

How can I solve this problem?

This is the code on the button:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik">

<a href="#download" target="_top">
<div>
<button id="comeceagora">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span> Comece Agora!
</button>
</div>
</a>

<style>
@media screen and (max-device-width : 1020px) {


button {
font-size: 15px!important;
animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
transition-delay: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes glow{
  from {
   box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00f498, 0 0 15px #00f498, 0 0 25px #00bcaa, 0 0 50px #00f498;
  }
  
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00f498, 0 0 25px #00bcaa, 0 0 50px #00f498, 0 0 55px #00f498;
  }
}

}
div {
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
padding: 60px;
}

button {
 position: relative;
 padding: 1em 2em;
 outline: none;
 border: 1px solid #303030;
 background: #000000;
 color: #00F498;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 font-size: 25px;
 overflow: hidden;
transition: 0.2s;
border-radius: 20px;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: "Rubik";
font-weight: 900;
}

button:hover {
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00F498, 0 0 25px #00BCAA, 0 0 50px #00F498;
transition-delay: 0.6s;
}
button span {
position: absolute;
}
button span:nth-child(1) {
top: 0;
left: -100%;
width: 100%;
height: 2px;
background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #00F498);
}
button:hover span:nth-child(1) {
left: 100%;
transition: 0.7s;
}
button span:nth-child(3) {
bottom: 0;
right: -100%;
width: 100%;
height: 2px;
background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #00F498);
}
button:hover span:nth-child(3) {
right: 100%;
transition: 0.7s;
transition-delay: 0.35s;
}
button span:nth-child(2) {
top: -100%;
right: 0;
width: 2px;
height: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #00F498);
}
button:hover span:nth-child(2) {
top: 100%;
transition: 0.7s;
transition-delay: 0.17s;
}
button span:nth-child(4) {
bottom: -100%;
left: 0;
width: 2px;
height: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(360deg, transparent, #00F498);
}
button:hover span:nth-child(4) {
bottom: 100%;
transition: 0.7s;
transition-delay: 0.52s;
}
button:active {
background: #00F498;
background: linear-gradient(to top right, #00F498, #00BCAA);
color: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 0 8px #00F498, 0 0 8px #00BCAA, 0 0 8px #00F498;
transition: 0.1s;
}
button:active span:nth-child(1) span:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(2) {
transition: none;
transition-delay: none;
}
</style>
```

The anchor is on the first button of the site: https://bldgprod.com.br

I'm very new to programming, all I know was researching and trying, so I ask that if possible explain to me in a simplified way.

Comment: You might first like to put your code through a validator. button is not alllowed as a child of an anchor (a) element. Then create a runnable snippet that shows the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Okay, I'll do that next time, as I mentioned, I'm new to the area and I'm learning, including how to ask.

Anyway, I still haven't found a solution to my problem and I don't think it's very productive for the community that I open another question... if anyone can help me, I'll be grateful, the problem can be visualized by opening the site and viewing in mobile mode after pressing F12.

Comment: You should edit this question, no need to open another one.